# C# WPF Canvas TouchAction.Up event is not firing

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm facing some issue with WPF TouchAction.Up event. It's not becoming fired. Other events Down and Move are working normal. I'm using Windows Simulator 14.0.

Have anybody faced such an issue?

Or may be there is another way to catch an UP event after Move?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by catching MainWindow_TouchUp event instead of TouchAction.Up event.

Thanks.